# How to output query result with line break and carriage return to text file in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

As the topic suggested, I'm looking for ways to be able to get the result in text out of the query, including line break(\n) and carriage return(\r).

As a matter of fact, I store JSON formatted data in a serialized text column. named it [data] column. The data column value is of large text size. 
It would be nice if there would be some solution that I can on the fly output it to the text file as well as retain data length, line break and carriage return.

I tried a couple of possible ways, such as.

> sqlcmd -S localhost -d Database1 -E -Q "select col1, col2, col3, col4, [data] from table1 " -o
>   "c:\outputfile.txt"

but with this solution, it includes table headers and the content get chopped in the middle.
I don't care if it would be done by manual, but copy from the SQL Management Studio is gonna take out all carriage returns and line breaks.

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use bcp.exe:

```
bcp.exe "select *  from NorthWind.dbo.orders" queryout "c:\testOrders.csv" -T -c -CRAW -t; -S"127.0.0.1"
```

[MSDN bcp Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)